# В textbox нет invoke, что делать?

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Почему `Invoke` не идёт в комплект `textbox` и что можно придумать?

P.S. Команда выполняется из асинхронного потока.

```
        chatboxedit.Invoke((Action)(() => { chatboxedit.text = message; }));
```

Comment: не не идет, а синтаксис похоже неверный. верный: ***.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { blablabla });

Comment: не идти может только с сторонними контролами плохого качества. это кривота, но поищите приведение к классу Control. а еще можно просто из this вызывать, я всегда только так и делаю.

Comment: @Rou1997 MainWindow (this), тоже не содержит определения Invoke, пробовал и по своемому и так как вы предложили. Дичь какая-то :(

Comment: Это WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @VladD проект создан как WPF

Comment: для wpf:   this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            { закрывающие сами ставьте

Comment: @Rou1997: Это для случая, когда фоновый поток является частью UI-контрола, чего по сути никогда не должно быть.

Comment: @VladD так должно быть и всегда есть, и не фоновый, а основной ака UI thread

Comment: @Rou1997: Э? Давайте ещё раз повторюсь: UI-контрол **не должен запускать фоновый поток**. Ну и код фонового потока не должен даже знать о существовании UI.

Comment: @VladD заладили, фоновый поток, фоновый поток. Invoke необходим для вызова кода в потоке контрола из другого потока. это нужно для того, чтобы обновить контрол или взять из него значение. вот. а потоком контрола управляет именно control1.Dispatcher. все логично, и ни разу слово фоновый или какой-то другой.

Comment: @Rou1997: Вопрос в том, откуда этот самый фоновый поток взялся. Если его запустил код окна, окно выполняет модельные задачи, и это просто неправильно.

Comment: @VladD когда как и кому как) да почти любой программист скажет, что код должен быть идеально стройным, но только проект бы не запустили с таким кодом, т.к. не хватило бы бабла, времени (плохое ведь быстрее делается) и мотивации) а вот как запустили, и проект взлетел, и денег принес - тогда пожалуйста, приводи в порядок не хочу

Comment: @Rou1997: Ну, с таким подходом и поля приватными делать не нужно, да и разбивать код на классы тоже.

Comment: @VladD чрезмерный бардак интуитивно ощущается. когда по проекту 
под андроид работал - писал код даже с опечатками в именах классов и т.д. для ускорения (у китайцев научился), но это оказалось неудачно, и оно же было и неприятно, благодаря чему эмпирически надо было понять, что стоит избегать опечаток все-таки. я и понял. где нужен отдельный класс - чувствую сразу. поля - да, часто сперва делаю публичными для удобства.

Comment: @Rou1997 это вы про меня ?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy видно же, что нет

Comment: @Rou1997 мда-уш, (-_-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WPF перебросом в UI-поток занимаются не контролы, а `Dispatcher`.

В простейшем случае можно сделать так:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { chatboxedit.text = message; });
```

---

С другой стороны, если вы пользуетесь WPF, то имеет смысл воспользоваться стандартным паттерном MVVM, и тогда

- ваши UI-классы не должны заниматься фоновой работой,
- текст в UI-контролы должен поступать в основном из привязок,
- в VM результаты фоновых вычислений должны через диспетчер поступать в основной поток, где их можно присваивать VM-свойствам (а UI обновится сам, через привязку).

Comment: Тут программа на "скорую руку", нет время думать об MVVM :)
Может и зря